# Python Script To Open Shell in Remote Server

Tags: python, ssh, scripting

I'm new in Python and i was trying to write a script to open a shell to remote server.

From local machine, system could be various Windows, Mac Or Linux, i want to ssh to a list of Linux servers using arguments, but one at a time.

For example, from my windows client, i would like to run command below to open a shell to remote server:

python myscript.py

The script needs to first detects the system of the local machine then run the command accordingly.

Could someone help me for it ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a citation that paramiko isn't compatible?

Comment: @Foon I have used paramiko which is powerful enough !